# How to unbind an onload event on an external SVG after it was initially completed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, onload, unbind

I have a rather complex and special issue. I have a `div` container which is initially hidden (`display: none`) and which is shown when a user clicks a button (using the jQuery function `show()`). Within this `div` is a svg visualization.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="parent">
    <object id='myObject' type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

The SVG vis I am loading with the following code:

```
fetch('LINK TO THE SVG FILE')
    .then(function(r) {return r.blob()})
    .then(function(b) { return myObject.data = URL.createObjectURL(b)})


myObject.onload = function() { // wait for the svg has loaded

    var myObject = this; // we're in the object's load event handler.
    var svg = d3.select(myObject.contentDocument) // get the contentDocument
        .select("svg"); // then get the svg inside
    //...some more styling things happen here
}
```

My issue is, that I don't know how (a.k.a. *where*) I should unbind the onload event because it gets triggered each time the user clicks on the button to change the `display` mode of the parent `div`. When I use the following code ...

```
fetch('LINK TO THE SVG FILE')
    .then(function(r) {return r.blob()})
    .then(function(b) { return myObject.data = URL.createObjectURL(b)})
    .then(function() {return myObject.onload = null})
```

... it never applies the style settings I perform within the `onload` function. Also when I add the `myObject.onload = null` setting to the end of my button's click event it won't fire the `onload` function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need the onload handler at all? Why not just add another `.then()` to the fetch which will be executed once that Promise is resolved, i.e. once the SVG has been loaded?

Comment: I did, as shown in the solution I wrote down in the second part of the post. However, I found out, that I unbinding the `onload` is not an option for me, because the SVG would need to be loaded each time I display the parent `div` or it would have no styling. I just add the SVG inline into my html and don't use the ´display: none` method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
fetch('LINK TO THE SVG FILE')
  .then(function(r) {return r.blob()})
  .then(function(b) {
     myObject.onload = function() { // wait for the svg has loaded
       // ...do what you need to...
       myObject.unload = null;
     }
     myObject.data = URL.createObjectURL(b)
  });
```